# The same amount of code works different with different data numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I create a project with Exchange model. There is a problem regarding how the same code functions differently with different data numbers (double type). 
Here is the spreadsheet where I underlined this problem.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zYxdFHdg1GhtSwj_mMB-eH_YD_PavMxuWDOSf-yeT5Q/edit?usp=sharing

link for code if needed https://script.google.com/d/10QwXa-RwpoDVQmfx9A_RzWJMcKVzi1hTyfkuIConmg8IIoG09zLrvnsy/edit?usp=sharing

I alse created a button "test" for usability. Below you can see the code. It's also in a spreadsheet file ofc.

```
function STtest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var test = ss.getSheetByName("Test");

  var MinD = test.getRange("C23").getValue(); //getting min
  var MaxD = test.getRange("C24").getValue(); // getting max
  var MinMaxRange;
  MinMaxRange = (MaxD - MinD) / 0.01; // range

  var i  = test.getRange("G8").getRow(); 
  var j  = test.getRange("G8").getColumn(); 

  var NewMinD = MinD + 0.01;

  test.getRange("G8").setValue(test.getRange("C23").getValue()); 
  //filling minimum price in new table 

  for (var k = 0 ; k < MinMaxRange-0.002; k++)   //fill all prices in new 
  table
  {  
      test.getRange(i+1, j).setValue(NewMinD);
      NewMinD = NewMinD+0.01;
      i = i + 1;
  }

  var i  = test.getRange("G8").getRow(); // reset index after loop

  var a  = test.getRange("A3").getRow(); 
  var b  = test.getRange("A3").getColumn(); 



  for (var w = 0 ; w < MinMaxRange-0.002; w++) //transporting bid/ask 
  //size in new table with right price
  {  
      if (test.getRange(i, j).getValue() == test.getRange(a,b+2).getValue()) 
      {
           test.getRange(i, j-1).setValue(test.getRange(a, b+1).getValue());
           test.getRange(i, j+1).setValue(test.getRange(a, b+3).getValue());
      }
      i = i + 1;
  } 
};
```

So you can see in a range "C3:C22" is random prices from 1.90 to 1.94.
If you replace these prices with a range above 2 (for example, try insert random values from 2.05 to 2.10), the code will not execute its last loop (which is commented in code as "//transporting bid/ask size in new table with right price"). 
How can it be fixed and why does it happens?

Comment: When you use the debugger, what do you notice about your function's variables, when you test the situations? Why not use batch methods and write whole arrays instead of value by value? Then you can inspect all values at once too.

Comment: What's the point of this `var i  = test.getRange("G8").getRow();` it's just another way of setting  `i=8;` and it doesn't with the contents of "G8".  So why not just use `var i=8;`

Comment: @Cooper yes, you are right, but this doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: @tehhowch i found in a debugger that somehow the value 2.07 can transform to 2.070040303 for example through this loop. So, i know found my solution to comparing not just values, but values with parseFloat + toFixed(2) transformation. I mean `if (parseFloat(test.getRange(i, j).getValue().toFixed(2)) == test.getRange(a, b+2).getValue());`  But i completely agree, that data arrays would be more suitable here. Thanks!

Comment: @sergei Apps Script is just JavaScript. All caveats of working with floating point numbers apply to it, as all numbers (even "integers") are represented in floating point (though JS integers have some special handling). If you are not familiar with the inaccuracy of floating point comparison, or the inability to represent a large number of floating point values exactly, then I suggest you review floating point at length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i now found my solution to comparing not just values, but values with parseFloat + toFixed(2) transformation. I mean `if (parseFloat(test.getRange(i, j).getValue().toFixed(2)) == test.getRange(a, b+2).getValue());` But i completely agree, that data arrays would be more suitable here. Thanks everyone for help anyway!